# How to add annotation to Plotly heat map using R language

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

```
library(complexHeatmap)
library(circlize)
p <- plot_ly(droplevels(data_Frame,
               x = ~factor(X),y=~Y,z=~Z,
               key=~Z,type = "heatmap",source = "heatplot")%>%    
               add_annotations(rowAnnotation(row_annotation_need_to_add="Type"))%>%
               layout(xaxis=list(title="X"),
                      yaxis=list(title="Y"),
                      theme_bw(16))
```

This is how I want my heat map but in r-plotly: 
[image: Inter image description here]

I am trying to add row annotation in r-plotly.
And they do have add_annotation, but I am looking for row annotation in r-plotly. If anyone could help me I would appreciate it. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to provide your dataset (with dput())

Comment: isn't dput() is used to write  an ASCII text representation of an R object to a file or connection, or uses one to recreate the objec

Comment: no just copy the content of your dataset (or a subset) with dput (yourdataset).

Comment: could you please explain how may i use dput() thank you MLavoie

Comment: got it thank you Mlavoie

Comment: can someone answer the question?